# If the sender is not in any of my address books, move the email to the Junk folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

My Outlook 2010 account has a number of address books, but unfortunately, no single address book has all my contacts.

So, I'm trying to create a rule (or combination of rules) that simply says, "if the sender is not in any of my address books, move the email to the Junk folder".

I can definitely get this to work for **one** address book using "except if...", but I can't figure out how to do an "except if" that includes **all** of my address books.

If this is possible, how is it done?

Comment: You might have to add a clause for each of your address books.

Comment: @DanD., that's what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: are you on exchange?

Comment: @Raystafarian, yes.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be much easier than I thought:

1. Under Junk Email Options > Options, select "Safe Lists Only".
2. Under Junk Email Options > Safe Senders, check "Also trust e-mail from my Contacts" and "Automatically add people I e-mail to the Safe Senders List.

Comment: The options are found under the Home tab > Delete section > Junk > Junk E-mail Options